# iptables redirect ip: port to another destination

Tags: iptables

I would like to know if it is possible to direct all connections that goes to IP X to another ip I can do this with the code below but are all ports I would like to do this only with port 80 and 443 is it possible?

/sbin/iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --dest 0.0.0.0 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's possible and pretty simple - you need add the match by transport protocol (tcp or udp) and destination port numbers. You can add the one rule per destination port number or create single rule for several port numbers. Note, that you cannot mix the port numbers of different protocols in single rule. Choose any way what you want.

`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d <ipX> -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DNAT --to <ipY>`